# Use <span> instead of <li> for wp_nav_menu()

Tags: theme-development, menus

I'm porting over a theme I made to Wordpress. For my menus, I used spans and not a list. I was trying to make wp_nav_menu output something like this: `<div ...><span><a>...</a></span><span><a>...</a></span></div>`, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just style the list items to inline-block like I'm assuming you used the span tags to do?

Comment: You can create a custom nav menu walker class and indicate that inside `wp_nav_menu`. Alternatively, you can grab the output of `wp_nav_menu` function, and str_replace `ul` and `li` with `div` & `span`.